# How to parse simple body content in AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How to I simply parse `1399508637585,2252`?

When I visit the desired page the above response is printed in browser. I've also tested with hurl.it:

```
HEADERS

Content-Length: 18
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 08 May 2014 00:23:57 GMT
Server: Werkzeug/0.9.4 Python/2.7.3
BODY

1399508637585,2252
```

Here is how I tried to parse the data:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/twonumbers',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(point) {
                var series = chart.series[0],
                    shift = series.data.length > 20;

                chart.series[0].addPoint(point, true, shift);

                setTimeout(requestData, 1000);    
            },
            cache: false
        });
    }
```

How to parse this data in order to write each number inside the array?

---

Update

Problem is that I cannot get this string in order to split.
Here is how I tried:

```
var tmp1 = point.split(',');                                   
chart.series[0].addPoint(tmp1[1], true, shift);
```

Comment: I'm not sure the format you're after, but if you want the string to be split by ",", with each side represented separately, you might look into parseInt() and String.split()
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: Why do you send plain text with a html content type header?

Comment: The back-end developer did it this way; there is no time to change that. But the big problem is that even if i split, i still dont get the data. See update

Comment: what do you get when you `console.log(point);` and `console.log(typeof point);`?

Comment: actually I get an error: '...No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource....' as I am making request to external ip not localhost

Comment: The problem was that i was making a request outside localhost, which is strange for me. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

The response should be a string so just split it where the , is and parseInt() on the index's on output.

so you'd do this to the returned data from the server response to your ajax call.

```
// turn to string if need be var responses = response.toString(); // turns number into a string
var pieces = responses.split(","); // two index's now for both numbers minus the ","

//pieces[0] = '1399508637585';
//pieces[1] = '2252';

// you can decide what to do after that, if you need it as an int just pieces[0] = parseInt(pieces[0]); etc...
```